# Is 10 is a Natural Number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was wondering that $10$ is a Natural number or not as it contains $0$ (zero) in it which is not a Natural number for sure, so $10$ is a Natural number or not ?

Comment: Of course 10 is a natural number. '10' is just a symbol. It is not really much related to 0. Moreover, often we consider 0 as a natural number as well.

Comment: Natural numbers are any integers 1 or more. Makes no difference what base is used, e.g. in base 2 most natural numbers have lots of 0's in them.

Comment: @Spark I have seen definitions which exclude 0.

Comment: @zz20s It depends on conventions.

Comment: @Spark of course,  I just wanted to let you know. personally, I include $0$, but that's beside the point.

Comment: Actually i thought that 0 was not invented when Natural Numbers system were proposed , And one more thing I have read that Natural Numbers are from 1 to infinity , and 0 & Natural Numbers together form the set of Whole numbers (is it right or not , if not kindly provide some reference so that i can clear my doubts ) . Thanks for replying so fast

Answer (score 4):

10 is of course a natural number, the successor of 9.

That we humans have the agreement to write numbers in base-10 notation has no effect on the numbers themselves, just on how we represent them in writing to each other.

you could write 10 as 1010 in binary or 101 in tertiary or A in hex, or any other base and it is still 10.

Comment: I really like this explanation as it hints into the deeper realm of math without getting to complicated. I would just further note that we define natural numbers traditionally as having a starting point and a successor operation. I'm not sure of an eloquent way to state that however.